# Vuetify Data Table: How to get divider in vertical table, and change the first column's background color?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

What I have now:

```
<v-data-table
  :items="kids"
>
  <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
    <tbody>
      <tr
        v-for="(header, index) in firstColumns"
        :key="header.text"
      >
        <td>
          {{ header }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ items[index] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </template>
</v-data-table>

data() {
  return {
    firstColumns: ['First', 'Second', 'Third'],
    kids: ['Edinson Cavani', 'Marcus Rashford', 'Christiano Ronaldo'],
  }
},
```

I managed to get the vertical table to look like this:

[image]

Next step, how do I get divider among the columns? I know there's :divider when we set the header, but since this is vertical table I do not set the :headers, so how do I set the divider here? Also, any how do I change the background color of the first column?

Ultimately, what I want to achieve look something like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Putting some CSS like `border-left: 1px solid grey;` on the second <td> element should work, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class name for the header and column cells to the header object of the column, e.g.

```
const header = [
  {
    text: 'My Column',
    value: 'my-column',
    class: 'with-divider',
    cellClass: 'with-divider'
  },
  ...
]
```

and style the cell as you like with css:

```css
.with-divider {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change css for first column in table, like this:

```css
table tr > td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background: lightgray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get vertical borders for all columns in Vuetify 3 data table I used this:

```
<style scoped>
  :deep() .v-table .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: thin solid rgba(var(--v-border-color), var(--v-border-opacity));
  }
  :deep() .v-table .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td:not(:last-child), .v-table .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > th:not(:last-child) { 
    border-right: thin solid rgba(var(--v-border-color), var(--v-border-opacity));
  }
</style>
```

Using `:deep()` is very important if you want to use scoped styling.